# General class Axioms

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, manchester-syntax

OWL AXIOM expressions:

**Given**: owl:class sport

**Output:** in  addition to the existing owl:object properties i want to add the  owl:object property *player* with the value Peter to every instance from type owl:class sport. That means that every individual from type owl:class sport should have this object property inherited with the value Peter.

My first thought was to express it with a general class axiom. Here i am not really sure whether this **a)** possible and **b)** better to do it with a SPARQL update query for isntance in Jena. What would you recommend me to do? And how would such a general class axiom look like, for isntance in owl manchester syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you don't need a general class axiom for this. You just want the "normal" subclass axiom:

Sport **subClassOf** (player **value** Peter)

which says that every instance of *Sport* has *Peter* as a value for the property *player*.

Comment: exactly, this is the solution. I already added this to my Ontology. Question is closed for me